# Rank = trace for idempotent nonsymmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, trace

If $A$ is idempotent and symmetric, one can show that the rank of $A$ equals its trace. Is such equality preserved in general if we only know that $A$ is idempotent and not necessarily symmetric?

Comment: The answers somehow "tacitly assume" that you know that every idempotent matrix is diagonalizable. Note that $t(1-t)$ is the minimal polynomial of an idempotent matrix and there is a certain connection between the powers of the factors of the minimal polynomial and the dimensions of the Jordan blocks in the normal form. The linearity of the factors here implies that all Jordan blocks have dimension one and hence every idempotent matrix is diagonalizable. Then one may make the desired conclusion about the rank by summing the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

If $A^2=A$ then $A$ is the identity on the image of $A$ (and of course zero on the kernel), hence with respect to a suitable basis, $A$ has $\operatorname{rank}A$ ones and otherwise zeroes on the diagonal, so $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{tr}A$

Comment: I thought I understand your answer but now I realize I'm missing something. For the claim "with respect to a suitable basis, $A$... zeroes on the diagonal", can you elaborate or point me to a reference? I only know of one but it requires symmetry.

Comment: The image of $A$ is also its $\lambda=1$ eigenspace. The kernel is also its $\lambda=0$ eigenspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is truce since the number of non-zero eigenvalue (counted up to multiplicity) is precisely the rank and an idempotent matrix has only zero or 1 eigenvalues.

Comment: Your first claim doesn't hold in general for nonsymmetric matrices. For example, consider $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The rank is $1$ whereas both eigenvalues are $0$.

Comment: But that matrix you mentioned is not an idempotent matrix. Given a idempoten matrix, it is always diagonalizable, therefore the number of non zero eigenvalues equals to the rank